# USB Printer not sending Endpoints

Tags: usb, c, arm

I am working on ARM & based LPC2468 controller interfacing with USB printer.I have successfully configured a Printer and it is working Properly. Now i came across a new printer Manufactured by Wipro,when i connected it to my device it didn't work.After researching a lot i came to know that my earlier USB printers (TVS, EPSON) use to send their endpoints (in and out)numbers during the setup phase(i.e in endpoint descriptor)but Wipro's printer send 0x00 
at the place on in and out endpoints. Is there any way by which i can know or assign endpoints(both in and out) to the Printer.

Comment: You can check the descriptors using `lsusb -v` in Linux. It is possible that the new printer differs significantly and your code simply fails to read them correctly.

Comment: Did you upload the appropriate firmware to the printer first?

Comment: Firmware in printer is already uploaded by the Manufacturer.

Comment: It might as well be a "Winprinter", a laser printer type whose firmware is extremely dumb, and is not able to work without its Windows driver software preprocessing the data to be printed... in that case you'd be in trouble. If the printer description page does not mention any printing languages (PS or PCL), and only Windows versions are listed as supported OS, you may start worrying.

Comment: You need to write appropriate driver for that printer if it does not fit to your controlling device. You need to know communication protocol and then adapt data from your device to the needs of the printer.

Comment: Have you tried enumerating all configurations? Maybe there just aren't any endpoints available in the default configuration.

Comment: The assumption that the printer firmware has already been loaded by the manufacturer is not necessarily valid - there may only be a small stub there, sufficient to accept the real operational firmware uploaded by the PC host at each power on.  If that is the case, you'll need something like a sizable SPI flash or SD card to hold it.  Invest some time in figuring out exactly what a Linux solution is doing when running this printer - and watch out especially for the possibility of it re-enumerating after load.  Of course you could also have a more fundamental USB-level problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following tests rely on connecting the printer to a Linux machine. Even if it's not Linux you are using on your ARM, this information is useful in identifying the protocol the printer is willing to use.

```
lsusb -v
```

should give you a list of all USB-connected devices. However, there is quite a variety of possibilities on how you actually have to drive your printer. Frequently, printers emulate 'old' printer interfaces: Serial port or Parallel port. If that is the case, your best bet is to check

```
dmesg
```

and see if the printer is listed in the events, and if it was recognized (and installed) as maybe ttyusbX or usblpX) or so. At this point, there should be information *how* Linux should be driving the devices (maybe HID or another protocol). If it's HID, then Linux will probably try to install its own driver. Could also be ACM (for serial emulation).

About the 0 endpoints: those are requisites by the USB norm. All USB peripherals must have an IN and OUT endpoint 0. During the setup, there should also appear at least one configuration (configuration 0). This is called the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual logo (more info = always better), I might be wrong, but it sounds like this company might own the printer:

http://www.wepindia.com/Support/Support.aspx

For some of their printers they do offer Linux drivers, so that's sort of good news. But it may still mean a porting effort, since it does look like they aren't really sticking to the normal protocols for everything. (Did some quick browsing on Ubuntu forums, the results were for parallel port devices, but there also some trouble with having to pre-process control flow etc).

If you're unlucky, this Indian outsourcing and consultancy firm built it and owned it:

[Link Archived by several Searchers as "Wipro Printer Drivers" page](http://www.wipro.com/products/drivers-download-product-certification.aspx)

They have, according to what I can find not only stopped their printer efforts, but seem to have found it helpful for the world at large to remove all pages related to them or their drivers. Where some archival systems and/or search engines remember several links to their efforts, none of them work and all result in the 404 you'll get when you click above. The company, to me, smells a bit B-grade-y (or even worse) too, so I'm happy to guess that even if they had drivers still downloadable they'd be all windows and all non-standard, like Laszlo suggests in the comments to your question.

Doing a search for "Wipro Driver USB Linux" gives only links, as far as I can see, to Parallel port WeP matrix printer discussions for Ubuntu, or points back to "Download Windows Drivers for Wipro xxxxxx". So, I'm not hopeful of this working easily for you.

I'm certainly not hopeful of it being a remotely good idea to try, unless you particularly like those kinds of torture, of course.

As you have seen already, it reports an impossible number of end-points, so from that you already know that they have a driver that just assumes a hard-coded number of endpoints, that the engineers decided on when they were choosing which chip to buy and how to flash it.

Anyway, I'm happy to forego any bounty, I just came across it because I was clicking around while procrastinating and got curious. I have now shared with you what I found and my impression of the matter, that is all I can give you, unfortunately.